# Dividing HTML Code Into PHP Sections---Having Errors With My PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a web page for a class.  It is a site designed for upcoming freshmen to receive information on the major(s) they are interested in.

For the assignment, I have to divide my original HTML code into a header.php, content.php, and footer.php.  I also have to use the POST method for my form with an action of $ SERVER[PHP SELF].  I also have to use a hidden input field in the form.

I have done all these tasks, but I think something is wrong with my heredoc print <<

I know I have some more work to do with my form, but I would really just love to see that the page will load correctly with my header, content, and footer.  Since I can't see anything, I don't want to go ahead and write out any other functions.  Would you please look at my PHP code and help me find this bug?  I'm sure I'm just overlooking something, but I'd appreciate the help!  Thanks!

Header.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>UNA Preview Day 2013</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="preview.css">
<script src="preview.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Content.php:

```
<!-- Tell script impaired users we *must* have Javascript -->
<noscript>
    <p class="alert">Sorry, this page requires Javascript!</p>
</noscript>

<img src= "banner.gif" alt = "UNA Logo" />
<br />
<h1>UNA Preview Day 2013</h1>
```

Footer.php

```
    <div class = "image">
    <img src = "unapic.png" alt = "UNA Logo" />
</div>
<p id = "footer">Copyright &copy; 2013 | University of North Alabama</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.php:

```
<?PHP
require("header.php");

if ($_POST[_submit_check])  { 
processForm();
}
else  {
displayForm();
}

function displayForm()  {
require("content.php");
}

require("footer.php");

if (array_key_exists('_submit_check', $_POST))  {
processForm();
}
else  {
displayForm();
} 

// ------------------------------------------------
function processForm()  {    //NEEDS WORK
print "Hello, $_POST[user]!";
}

function display_form()  {
//require("content.php");  

print <<<HTMLBLOCK
 <html>
    <head> 
    <title>UNA Preview Day 2013</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name = "contact" method = "POST" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">                
    <div class = "appearance">
    *All fields required.*<br /><br />
    Name: *  <input title="Name required!" type = "text" id = "name" name = "name"        required autofocus onchange = "validName();" size = 30>
    <br />
    Email: * <input title="Email address of form username@domain required!" type =   "email" placeholder = "me@example.com" id = "email" name = "email" 
    required onchange = "validAddress();" size = 30>
    <br /><br /><br />
    Areas of Study <br />
    Check the program(s) in which you are interested in. (*Check AT LEAST one.*) <br />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "cs" name = "option[]">Computer Science<br />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "cis" name = "option[]">Computer Information Systems<br     />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "ddep" name = "option[]">Dual Degree Engineering    Program<br /><br /><br />
    <div class = "center">
        <input type="button" value="Send" onClick = "return validOption()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </div>
    <input type = "hidden" name="_submit_check" value="1">  
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    </form>
    </body>
</html> 
HTMLBLOCK;  
}
?>
```

Comment: You are `require`-ing `footer.php` from within `footer.php`? What php errors are you getting?

Comment: Looks like you're merging your `index.php` with `footer.php` to me.  Try creating an `index.php` file and requiring the header, footer, and content there.

Comment: It seems like in your `index.php` you are merging with `header.php`, and both already have `<head>` and `<body>` elements declared. You shouldn't have duplicates of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made you something really ugly below. But yeah you need to declare all your functions before you call them so have them in your header or even better in a seperate file and `require_once('functions.php');` at the very top of your header.

You spelt your function as displayForm() then lower you put display_form(). Make sure you keep to a naming convention else it wont work.

Also make sure you keep only 1 tag of `<html><body><title>` tag even if you have multiple files you only need one for the whole document if that makes sense.

When checking if submit. I changed to if(isset($_POST['_submit_check']){} but what ever works for you.

Netbean is my favourate text editor it can help you debug in future.

```
<!------- Start of header.php --------->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>UNA Preview Day 2013</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="preview.css">
<script src="preview.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Tell script impaired users we *must* have Javascript -->
<noscript>
    <p class="alert">Sorry, this page requires Javascript!</p>
</noscript>

<img src= "banner.gif" alt = "UNA Logo" />
<br />
<h1>UNA Preview Day 2013</h1>

<?php

function displayForm()  {
//require("content.php");  
$htmlblock = '
    <form name = "contact" method = "POST" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">                
    <div class = "appearance">
    *All fields required.*<br /><br />
    Name: *  <input title="Name required!" type = "text" id = "name" name = "name"        required autofocus onchange = "validName();" size = 30>
    <br />
    Email: * <input title="Email address of form username@domain required!" type =   "email" placeholder = "me@example.com" id = "email" name = "email" 
    required onchange = "validAddress();" size = 30>
    <br /><br /><br />
    Areas of Study <br />
    Check the program(s) in which you are interested in. (*Check AT LEAST one.*) <br />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "cs" name = "option[]">Computer Science<br />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "cis" name = "option[]">Computer Information Systems<br     />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "ddep" name = "option[]">Dual Degree Engineering    Program<br /><br /><br />
    <div class = "center">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onClick = "return validOption()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </div>
    <input type = "hidden" name="_submit_check" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    </form>';
    return $htmlblock;
}
function processForm()  {    //NEEDS WORK
$message= "Hello, ";
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $message.=$_POST['name'];
}
return $message;
}
?>
//// END OF HEADER  ///////////
//// START OF CONTENT //////////
<?php
if (isset($_POST['_submit_check']))  {



echo processForm();
}
else  {
echo displayForm();
}
?>
<!---- END OF CONTENT ------>
<!---- START OF FOOTER ------->

</body>
</html>

<!----- END OF FOOTER  ------->
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I really appreciate it!  I'm still having some trouble, but I think I'm making a breakthrough!  Thanks again Jason, Terry, Drew, & Sumarai for taking the time to help!

Comment: Just updated it. Sorry its messy I'm still learning too, but I managed to get the form to submit and display stuff. I changed the input type button to submit, so it would submit. Hope it helps somehow. Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much Jason!  This has really and truly been a major help to me.  My page is displaying correctly now with a header, content, and footer.  That was my main issue so now I think I can write some more PHP code to get this page more functional!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There is a:

```
require("footer.php");
```

in your footer.php that is creating an infinite loop

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, but I just noticed that I forgot to paste my Footer.php.  What I originally posted as Footer.php was actually my Index.php.  Sorry, I'm tired!